# Can a rosbridge HTML client access ROS parameters?

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can an HTML client connecting to rosbridge (v1 or v2) access ROS parameters?   I am developing a rosbridge/HTML5/javascript GUI to teleop my robot and I'm wondering if I can set a number of parameters in the launch file used to fire up rosbridge and then access those parameters from the HTML/javascript client.

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43828/can-a-rosbridge-html-client-access-ros-parameters?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that you can with rosbridge 1.0; there's a psuedo-service call that you can make to get and set parameters. I can't find the documentation for it at the moment; it shouldn't be too hard to find in you grep the source for rosbridge.py.

**EDIT:** In rosbridge 1.0, it looks like these services are `/rosbridge/get_param` and `/rosbridge/set_param` (rosbridge/bin/rosbridge.py lines 89-107)

I assume that it's possible with rosbridge 2.0 as well, but it's a fairly new project and the documentation doesn't seem complete just yet. Again, a short tour through the source should find it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-09-14**:
Thanks Austin.  So far I haven't be able to find the magic incantation in the source but I will keep looking...

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-09-17**:
Awesome!  Thanks Austin.  Dunno how I missed that since I was grep'in left and right among the files for "param" but obviously did something wrong.  In any event, this will be very useful.